# Is it possible to use iPython widgets in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, ipython, ipywidgets

I've been using iPython widgets in a Jupyter notebook, but the extension I was depending on to enable App Mode is not working, so I've decided to try to rewrite it all to Python/Flask, but I have no idea how, or if it's at all possible, to use iPython widgets in Flask views (especially interactive)?

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

items_layout = widgets.Layout(flex='1 1 auto',
                      width='400px', height='200px')

box_layout = widgets.Layout(display='flex',
                    flex_flow='row',
                    align_items='stretch',
                    width='100%')

instruction = widgets.Textarea(description="Command",
                               value = "",
                               layout = items_layout)

code = widgets.Textarea(description="Code",  
                        value = "",
                        layout = items_layout)

interactive_plot = widgets.interactive(run_code, trigger = instruction)

items = [interactive_plot, code]
box = widgets.Box(children=items, layout=box_layout)
display(box)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is response from ipywidgets repository [issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1586) about similar subject.

> In order for the widgets to do something, they must be hooked up to a kernel to do the computation. This requires some extra javascript code and a server somewhere that is providing the python kernel. The web3 example shows one way to do this.

[Example](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/tree/6.x/jupyter-js-widgets/examples/web3) of using ipywidgets in web service.

However you will not be able to write widgets code in Python. The whole display of widgets is done with JavaScript code.